# Trying to write a program to deal 5 random cards to a hand for poker

Tags: java

Using the ThinkJava textbook Chapter 14 (objects of objects) and code supplied as a place to start. I am overwhelmed and lost with where to start and what would work. Below is all of the code I am working with. "Hand" is currently an extension of "card collection".

> "Write an original Java program to implement the basic structure of a poker game. The program should create a deck of 52 playing cards, create at least 2 empty hands, and deal 5 random cards to each hand. One way to randomize the deal is to shuffle the deck first. The program should show the hands by either printing them on the console or drawing them with the card table code."

Given code that defines the card collection:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A collection of playing cards.
 */

public class CardCollection {

    private String label;
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty collection.
     */
    public CardCollection(String label) {
        this.label = label;
        this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the label of the card collection.
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * Adds the given card to the collection.
     */
    public void addCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the card with the given index.
     */
    public Card popCard(int i) {
        return cards.remove(i);
    }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the last card.
     */
    public Card popCard() {
        int i = size() - 1;
        return popCard(i);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of cards.
     */
    public int size() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    /**
     * True if the collection is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean empty() {
        return cards.size() == 0;
    }

    /**
     * Moves n cards from this collection to the given collection.
     */
    public void deal(CardCollection that, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Card card = popCard();
            that.addCard(card);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Moves all remaining cards to the given collection.
     */
    public void dealAll(CardCollection that) {
        int n = size();
        deal(that, n);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the card with the given index.
     */
    public Card getCard(int i) {
        return cards.get(i);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the last card.
     */
    public Card last() {
        int i = size() - 1;
        return cards.get(i);
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the cards at indexes i and j.
     */
    public void swapCards(int i, int j) {
        Card temp = cards.get(i);
        cards.set(i, cards.get(j));
        cards.set(j, temp);
    }

    /**
     * Randomly permute the cards.
     */
    public void shuffle() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int j = random.nextInt(i);
            swapCards(i, j);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the card collection.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return label + ": " + cards.toString();
    }

}

Code that I have modified a little to build the hand of cards

/**
 * A hand of playing cards.
 */

public class Hand extends CardCollection {

    /**
     * Constructs an empty hand.
     */
    public Hand(String label) {
        super(label);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the label and cards.
     */
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(getLabel() + ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(getCard(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Hand h = new Hand("one");
        Card c = new Card(13,3); //(rank, suit)
        h.addCard(c);
        System.out.println(h);
    }

}

Defines what a card is

/**
 * A standard playing card.
 */

public class Card {

    public static final String[] RANKS = {
        null, "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    public static final String[] SUITS = {
        "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    private final int rank;

    private final int suit;

    /**
     * Constructs a card of the given rank and suit.
     */
    public Card(int rank, int suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a negative integer if this card comes before
     * the given card, zero if the two cards are equal, or
     * a positive integer if this card comes after the card.
     */
    public int compareTo(Card that) {
        if (this.suit < that.suit) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.suit > that.suit) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.rank < that.rank) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.rank > that.rank) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the given card has the same
     * rank AND same suit; otherwise returns false.
     */
    public boolean equals(Card that) {
        return this.rank == that.rank
            && this.suit == that.suit;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the card's rank.
     */
    public int getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the card's suit.
     */
    public int getSuit() {
        return this.suit;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the card's index in a sorted deck of 52 cards.
     */
    public int position() {
        return this.suit * 13 + this.rank - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the card.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return RANKS[this.rank] + " of " + SUITS[this.suit];
    }

}

The deck to work from

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A deck of playing cards (of fixed size).
 */

public class Deck {

    private Card[] cards;

    /**
     * Constructs a standard deck of 52 cards.
     */
    public Deck() {
        this.cards = new Card[52];
        int index = 0;
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
                this.cards[index] = new Card(rank, suit);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a deck of n cards (null).
     */
    public Deck(int n) {
        this.cards = new Card[n];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the internal cards array.
     */
    public Card[] getCards() {
        return this.cards;
    }

    /**
     * Displays each of the cards in the deck.
     */
    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(this.cards[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the deck.
     */
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(this.cards);
    }

    /**
     * Chooses a random number between low and high, including both.
     */
    public int randomInt(int low, int high) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the cards at indexes i and j.
     */
    public void swapCards(int i, int j) {
    }

    /**
     * Randomly permutes the array of cards.
     */
    public void shuffle() {
    }

    /**
     * Finds the index of the lowest card
     * between low and high inclusive.
     */
    public int indexLowest(int low, int high) {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the cards (in place) using selection sort.
     */
    public void selectionSort() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a subset of the cards in the deck.
     */
    public Deck subdeck(int low, int high) {
        Deck sub = new Deck(high - low + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < sub.cards.length; i++) {
            sub.cards[i] = this.cards[low + i];
        }
        return sub;
    }

    /**
     * Combines two previously sorted subdecks.
     */
    public static Deck merge(Deck d1, Deck d2) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a sorted copy of the deck using merge sort.
     */
    public Deck mergeSort() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reorders the cards (in place) using insertion sort.
     */
    public void insertionSort() {
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: i thin the problem is that he doesn't know what he is doing, his void main is just creating the hand, creating the card, and adding the card to the hand....

Comment: @InkedMom91: FYI, you can't just "withdraw" a question once other users have invested their time in trying to answer it. In the "legal" page linked from the bottom of every page here, it says: "You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange [...] even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You."

Answer (score 1):

first your void main needs to create the deck and not the card

```
public static void main()
{
    Hand h = new Hand("one");
    Deck D = new Deck();
    h.addCard(c);
    System.out.println(h);
}
```

then you have to build your functions to shuffle and deal cards

inside deck there's an array called Cards, you have to permute that array 
you'll need somethink like this

```
public void shuffle()
{
    //code to shuffle your deck
}
```

Finally to deal card should deal the top card of your deck, and then remove the card from the deck

```
int dealcardindex = 0;

    public card Dealcard()
    {
            Card DealedCard = this.Cards[dealcardindex];
            dealcardindex++;
            return DealedCard ;
    }
```

finally you'll have something like this on your void main

```
public static void main()
{
    Hand h1 = new Hand("one");
    Hand h2 = new Hand("two");
    Deck D = new Deck();
    Deck.Shuffle();
    h1.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h1.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h1.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h1.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h1.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h2.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h2.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h2.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h2.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    h2.addCard(Deck.Dealcard());
    System.out.println(h);
}
```